# How to reference to another object

Tags: java, object, parameters

I'm doing a homework question, and I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. The homework question I've been given is the following:

[image]

I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

My code so far:

```
public class Person //This is the class
{
    String firstName;
    String familyName;
    boolean isFemale;
    Person partner;
}
```

My method so far is:

```
Person getAngelinaJolie() //This is the method
{
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.firstName = "Angelina";
    person1.familyName = "Jolie";
    person1.isFemale = true;
    person1.partner.firstName = "Brad";
    person1.partner.familyName = "Pitt";
    return person1;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but you really should post your error message inline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate Angelina's partner, and I would think it would be in the constructor of Person or in the getter method.

For simplicity sake for your assignment, you can just say

```
Person getAngelinaJolie() //This is the method
{
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.firstName = "Angelina";
    person1.familyName = "Jolie";
    person1.isFemale = true;
    person1.partner = new Person();//must create the object!
    person1.partner.firstName = "Brad";
    person1.partner.familyName = "Pitt";
    return person1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a variable `partner` that can hold a `Person`, but you haven't actually put anything inside the variable. Before trying to access the fields on `partner`, say `person1.partner = new Person();`.

Comment: Yeah i did that. Now it's giving me this error - http://prntscr.com/1xerjb @chylis

Comment: @blueJavaMAN This means that there's additional code that you're not showing in this problem. Most likely, there's an existing "Brad Pitt" object that you're supposed to assign instead of creating a new one, but (1) we'd have to see the code, and (2) paste errors as text instead of linking to images.

Comment: Um yeah. In the instructions shown, it's asking to create and use an additional field for partner. But im  not quite sure how to use an additional field for partner

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your variable. With person one, you typed

```
Person person1 = new Person();
```

And rightly so. However, you **forgot to do this with partner**

EDIT: For future reference, include your in-line error. If you don't have one, switch your IDE to eclipse or something else.